# Exponent of group-4

Tags: group-theory

Let be $G$ locally finite group. Let $H\unlhd G$ is nilpotent of class at most 2. Set $K\leq H$ with $exp(K)=m$ (exponent.). Show that $K^{G}$ (normal closure in $G$) has $m$-bounded exponent.

I do know if K is abelian.
Help!

Comment: Are you assuming that $G$ is nilpotent of class 2, or just $H$? And what exactly do you mean by $m$-bounded exponent?

Comment: Just H. Exponent that depends only on a function of m alone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Too long for a comment.

An idea: $\,K^G\le H\,$ so it is nilpotent and of class at most 2 . If we could prove it is generated by elements of order bounded by $\,m\,$ then the claim would follow by [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/138452/nilpotent-group-and-exponent) (and this uses the locally finite condition) or, of course, if its class number is one then you've already proved it.

Thus, we know that $\,K^G/Z(K^G)\,$ is abelian so the result is true for this quotient. Assuming that by "$\,m$-bounded exponent" you meant "exponent that depends only on a function of $\,m\,$ alone", say $\,f(m)\,$, we have that $x^{f(m)}\in Z(K^G)\,$ for all $\,x\in K^G\,$...and I can't continue much longer.

Hopefully the above will help you.